# NSApp beginSheet:modalForWindow: deprecated in El Capitan

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Thanks for the help. Need guidance with fixing code to call sheet in 10.11.

Current and deprecated code:

```
[NSApp beginSheet:customPanel modalForWindow:[_sourceTabView window]
    modalDelegate:nil
   didEndSelector:NULL
      contextInfo:NULL];
```

How would I fix this using [NSWindow beginSheet:completionHandler:]

Thanks again.
Paul.

Comment: You know the method to use. Try and write a bit yourself and ask for help if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

Documentation says

> ```
> - (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow modalDelegate:(nullable id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(nullable SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(null_unspecified void *)contextInfo NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_0, 10_10, "Use -[NSWindow beginSheet:completionHandler:] instead");
> ```

```
  [[ _sourceTabView window] beginSheet:customPanel
                     completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode){
    //your code
  }
```

Comment: Since OP's original code specified no modal delegate or did-end selector, he can just pass `nil` for the completion handler.